# HttpClient Header if-match Firebase Database Realtime

Tags: c#, firebase, api, rest, xamarin

Estoy trabajando con Firebase Database Real-Time intentando hacer lo siguiente:

1. Obtener un valor de tipo int
2. Sumarle 1
3. Subirlo solo si el valor no cambio
4. En caso de que haya cambiado, obtener el nuevo valor y repetir el proceso hasta que se logre subir

Por ahora pude obtener el valor, sumarle 1 y subirlo, pero sin que checkee que el valor en el servidor sigue siendo el mismo de antes.
Investigando encontre que se puede poner un Header, pero no entiendo como usarlo, es muy complejo y me supera.. Por aca en Argentina Buenos Aires no encuentro a nadie que pueda enseñarme a hacerlo y en internet no encuentro info que logre entender y me sirva.

Lo mas util que encontre fue esto:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/samples/conditional-operations-csharp

Probe haciendo:

```
request.Headers.Add("If-Match", "*");
```

Pero no logro hacer que funcione, me pasa que se sube el dato sin checkear o tirando una excepcion, tampoco entendi donde pongo el valor con en el que tiene que checekar ..

Lo que ando haciendo es una app con Xamarin.Forms que sube las respuestas de los usuario y estas se descargan desde una web y hace reportes en Excel y graficos tortas en un PDF, todo esta hecho y funciona perfecto, menos esta parte.

Les paso mi codigo:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string url = "https://lucasbica.firebaseio.com/contador/.json";

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            //GET
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(responseBody); //Console: 10

            //PUT
            int intValue = int.Parse(responseBody);
            intValue++;
            response.Content = new StringContent(intValue.ToString());
            await client.PutAsync(url, response.Content);

            //GET
            response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(responseBody); //Console: 11
        }
    }
}
```